# Show image using function

Tags: mysql, vb.net, function

I'm new to VB. NET so please bear with me. In the code below, I have a picture box in my main form and I want the selected query profile_picture to show in the picture box but I have no idea what the function should return

```vb
Public Sub ShowPicture(ByVal username As String)
    user = username
    Dim dsSearch As DataSet
    ModuleQuery.Showpic(username)

    Dim dSearch As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("Photo"), Byte())
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(dsSearch)
    prof_pic.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

End Sub
```

This is a module which includes all SELECT queries so that it won't be messy.
I want to call a function but I don't know what to return so that I can show the image

```vb
Public Function Showpic(ByVal user As String)
    Dim FunctionErrorState As Boolean = False
    Dim InsertError As Boolean = False
    Dim CloseError As Boolean = False

    Dim dsData As New DataSet
    Dim bite As Byte()
    Try
        openDB()
        'MyADOConnection.Open()


        Dim myQuery As String = "SELECT profile_picture FROM coa.register WHERE username = '" & user & "'"

        Dim myCommand As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(myQuery)

        dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader

        bite = DirectCast(dr("Photo"), Byte())


    Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
        InsertError = True


    End Try
    Try
        MyADOConnection.Close()
    Catch exclose As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
        CloseError = True

    End Try
    If InsertError Then
        FunctionErrorState = True
    End If

    Return bite 'I just put something random here since I don't know what to retun
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the image is being stored as a byte array in the database. You (i guess correctly) read this array from the database with the command `bite = DirectCast(dr("Photo"), Byte())` in your `ShowPic` function. A byte array is just a large blob of data in memory, that you later query with the `MemoryStream`.

Therefore your `ShowPic` function (which is more a `GetPic` function ;-) should return `Byte()`

```vb
Public Function Showpic(ByVal user As String) As Byte()
```

You should initialize `bite` with `Nothing`

```vb
Dim bite As Byte() = Nothing
```

That way if an error occurs, the array will be nothing and you can check for that.

In order to convert the byte array, that contains the raw image data into an image you correctly use a `MemoryStream` and the `Image.FromStream` method. I/O in .NET works in large portions with streams. They are just a way to continously feed data from some source. In this case the source is just the memory, in particular the Byte array you got from the database.

You however never use that Byte array. Assign the result of the `ShowPic` function to a variable, in order to use it:

```vb
Public Sub ShowPicture(ByVal username As String)
    user = username
    Dim ImageData As Byte() = ModuleQuery.Showpic(username)
    If ImageData IsNot Nothing Then
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(ImageData)
            prof_pic.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        End Using
    Else
        'Your function returned nothing, so an error occured.
        'This is a very crude way of error handling, since you never
        'see the error in the first place, which makes debugging a
        'nightmare. There are better ways, out of scope of this answer.

        MessageBox.Show("No image retrieved due to an error :(")
    End If
End Sub
```

That way you retrieve the image data from the database (again, rename it to `GetPic` or `GetImageData` or something) in `ShowPic` and return its raw data to the `ShowPicture` method where you decode and show it.